# mystery unknown alien interface for OnItemClickListener, how to implement

Tags: android, coverflow, onitemclicklistener

i am trying to add an OnItemClickListener to a coverflow app for android,  one where the images can scroll back and forth and the part i wanted to add was an on click listener so you can click on one of the images and go to another activity.  i am guessing that it works the same way you would if you were adding an OnItemClick to a listview or a gridview filled with images.  I understand that this question has been asked before, however this case is different.  there is additional code in the app that does not make sense.  here is where the code comes from http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html  and this app has the following four java classes:

CoverFlow.java  //  extends CoverAbsSpinner and implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener

CoverAdapterView.java  // class extends Adapter and ViewGroup classes

CoverAbsSpinner.java  // this class extends CoverAdapterView.java

CoverFlowExample.java  // extends Activity

and the strange thing is this code shown below that i found in the CoverAdapterView.java class.  it does not make sense to place what looks like a useless interface stuck in the middle of the class. and it says "Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked."

this is the mystery of the method.  how do you "call" this?  did they actually prepare the OnItemClickListener?   do i override this thing or what?

and for the reason of this code in not yet understood?  anyone know what the purpose of this is? it is an interface that you have to implement or override anyway.  so i question the purpose of this.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
     * been clicked.
     * <p>
     * Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need
     * to access the data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param parent The AdapterView where the click happened.
     * @param view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this
     *            will be a view provided by the adapter)
     * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
     * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked.
     */
    void onItemClick(CoverAdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id);


}
/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
 * been clicked.
 *
 * @param listener The callback that will be invoked.
 */
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = listener;
}

/**
 * @return The callback to be invoked with an item in this AdapterView has
 *         been clicked, or null id no callback has been set.
 */
public final OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
    return mOnItemClickListener;
}

/**
 * Call the OnItemClickListener, if it is defined.
 *
 * @param view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked.
 * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
 * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked.
 * @return True if there was an assigned OnItemClickListener that was
 *         called, false otherwise is returned.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for coverflow click listner try to use this.

```
coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        switch(position) 
        {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(****.this,@@@@.class));
                finish();
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(****.this, ####.class));
                finish();
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(****.this, &&&&.class));
                finish();
                break;

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i understand that you have to stick this OnItemClickedListener inside the OnCreate method right?  do i just put it anywhere in the OnCreate or the last thing all the way down after all the other code?   often i hear people say that it has to go after the setContentView method, not sure it that is true in this case.

Comment: Yes you have to palce OnItemClickedListener inside OnCreate method, anywhere but after setContentVIew and declaring all widgets of android.

Comment: i put the code for coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener in the OnCreate method in the right place after the setContentView and in Eclispe IDE the setOnClickListener is marked as error, so i hovered over it and the options gave by Quickfix is the following:                 (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} is Undefiend for the type Coverflow)     8 quick fixes available: change to 'setOnClickListener'(...)   change to SetOnItemLongClickListener(..) Create Method 'setOnItemClickListener(On Item click Listener) in type coverflow'   any ideas?

Comment: Hve you properly made object of CoverFlow. And you have to create a class of CoverFlow.

Comment: public class CoverFlowExample extends Activity {
       @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
     CoverFlow coverFlow;
     coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);
     
     coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

     ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this);
     
     coverImageAdapter.createReflectedImages();
     
     coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);
     
     coverFlow.setSpacing(-15);
     coverFlow.setSelection(8, true);
     
     setContentView(coverFlow)

Comment: // and there is this abstract class that is included:  public abstract class CoverAdapterView<T extends Adapter> extends ViewGroup {    //and there is an abstract onItemclick listener:  /**
     * The listener that receives notifications when an item is selected.
     */
    OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelectedListener;